# How can I find which process is controlling the root window?

Tags: x11, xorg, cinnamon, window-manager, xinit

I'm trying to get an xscreensaver to run as my desktop background / wallpaper using the method described here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XScreenSaver#Animated_wallpaper and the first step is killing the process that controls the root X window, but I have no idea what process that is.

Ideally I'd like to learn how to obtain the name of this program myself [incidentally `ps aux | grep root` doesn't really help] and from there figure out how to stop this program from starting at boot or asserting control of the root X window.

However, anyone who knows offhand what program this would be in Cinnamon can help me solve the problem and naturally any additional information about stopping / disabling this program or starting / enabling `/usr/lib/xscrensaver/glmatrix -root` would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root Window is a special Window of the X server. It doesn't have an associated application.

The wiki improperly refers to the *root window* here. What they meant is a Window that masks/hides the root Window like typically found in modern desktop environments (usually referred to as the *Desktop*, and often implemented by a file manager showing you the content of a `~/Desktop` folder).

Those `xscreensaver` widgets actually work by updating the content of the root Window. So you need to remove that *Desktop* window that would hide it and any other Window that is displayed on top of the root window.

What you could try looking for is the process id of the windows that register a "Window Type" of "Desktop" with the window manager. You could do something like:

```
xwininfo -tree -root |
  pcregrep -o '^\s+\K0x\S+' |
  xargs -n1 xwininfo -wm -id |
  pcregrep -Mo '(?s)Window type:\s+Desktop.*?Process id: \K\d+' |
  sort -u
```

(`xwininfo -tree` to list all the windows,  the first `pcregrep` to extract their window id, the second xwininfo to retrieve the WM properties (including Window type and pid) of each and then the second `pcregrep` to extract the PID of those *Desktop* windows).

You could also run:

```
xprop _NET_WM_PID
```

And click on the desktop. Or even:

```
xkill
```

And click on the desktop to kill that window.

In any case, note that it may not be safe to kill that window/process as it may very well be handled by some essential process like the window manager.

In the case of `cinnamon`, at least on a default desktop environment on Linux mint 18.1 cinnamon edition, it seems to be `nemo` though (the cinnamon file manager), so there's little harm killing it.

Comment: ok so i found the program is specifically nemo-desktop, and i disabled it from starting on login, now i have no desktop icons, and if i try to attain the pid as described it returns null even as root, yet something is still being drawn over the xscreensaver, which appears only for a few seconds when i restart cinnamon [ctrl+alt+esc], any idea what it might be?

Comment: @0x5f3759df, does `xprop _NET_WM_PID` or `xwininfo` and click on that not reveal what that is?

Comment: xrpop says "_NET_WM_PID not found" even when using sudo

Comment: @0x5f3759df,  `_NET_WM_PID`, not `xprop _NEW_WM_PID`. What about `xwininfo`? Or `xwininfo -all`?

Comment: xwininfo: Window id: 0x340002d (has no name)

  Root window id: 0xd5 (the root window) (has no name)
  Parent window id: 0xd5 (the root window) (has no name)
     0 children.

Comment: tiny keyboard typos

Comment: @0x5f3759df, you could run `diff <(ps -eo args) <(xkill; ps -eo args)` to see what process goes when you kill that window.

Comment: this one wont die even with sudo

Comment: @0x5f3759df, I think it's down to the window manager being a compositing window manager. Try replacing with a simple one see if that makes a different (`fvwm2 --replace` for instance).

Comment: hey that works! its ugly tho. im trying to find a way to disable compositing in muffin [cinnamon wm] now.

Answer (score 0):

Your title is missleading, to find the root window you could do:

```
xprop -root | grep PID
```

With the `-root` flag you can omit the click on the desktop and with `grep PID` you can find the PID of your root window, even when you use an obscure WM. Well it probably won't work with TWM.

On my end the output looks like tis:

```
xprop -root | grep PID
I3_PID(CARDINAL) = 3134
```

But this process doesn't set your wallpaper. You cannot kill the program that sets your wallpaper because it just does that an then exits. (You should not kill your window manager but there is no harm in killing nemo.)

I suggest you try to disable the wallpaper in cinnamon:

Thist answer on [Linux Questions](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/how-to-remove-background-in-cinnamon-desktop-4175556682/) might help: `System Settings > Backgrounds > Settings > Picture Aspect 'No Picture'`

If this doesn't work you have to disable the desktop:

`man nemo` says:

```
   --no-desktop
          Do  not  manage  the desktop — ignore the preference
          set in the preferences dialog.
```

And in the [i3 faq](https://faq.i3wm.org/question/3083/nemo-launches-a-desktop-window-linux-mint-16-cinnamon.1.html) you will find that this command will disable the desktop window for nemo:

```
gsettings set org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons false
```

Comment: That's the pid or your window manager, usually not the process that displays a "desktop window" that masks the root window. Not all window manager will add such a property to the root Window. Cinnamon doesn't seem to.

Comment: Usually there is no difference between `xprop -root` and `xprop <CLICK ON DESKTOP>`. If there is a difference in Cinnamon, my answer works for most WM/DM except Cinnamon. The programs that set the wallpaper (i.e. xsetroot) send a property change signal to the root window, they do not display a desktop window. This has to be the same under Cinnamon. - But _NET_WM_PID is set? Then it is my WM that isn't standard and because there are some others that are not, I grep for `PID`.

Comment: We're not talking of the root window here (the root windows has no application, `xsetroot` changes root window attributes and then exits). the arch wiki is actually referring to a window that masks/hides the root window. That is generally a file manager (like `nemo` on cinnamon or `pcmanfm` on LXDE) that displays a background and some icons.

Comment: You are right, I just started nautilus and now my desktop wallpaper has changed and a window named 'desktop' appears, it has Icons in it :). But when I kill this desktop window my wallpaper stays the same. That means it works like `xsetroot` but it doesn't exit, because it has to show some icons. I think you cannot find out the program that did set the wallpaper. hmm, and that was never the question. It was the title..

Comment: something is still being drawn on top of xscreenaver, even with no running instances of nemo or nemo-desktop, any idea what it might be?

Comment: How does this something look like?

Comment: its the grey to black gradient i use as a wallpaper